# How to call a method of the MapActivity from another activity in Android?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, firebase, google-maps-api-3

I am working on an Android application that based on Google Maps API. I have a `refresh()` method to refresh my `MapActivity`. I want to call the `refresh()` method to refresh the map after I managed my POIs from another activity.

```
MapActivity.refresh();
```

This is my `refresh()` method:

```
public void refresh() {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    finish();
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

I know I can call this method from other activities if it is `static`. So, I made this following change:

```
public static void refresh() {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    finish();
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

After that, I get this message:

```
Non-static method 'getIntent()' cannot be referenced from a static context
```

Is there another way to refresh the map?

Comment: you can use map.clear() that will clear all points on map and put another points...

Comment: Dude, why do u need refresh method ? when u can clear map data and reset it again (with updated data)

Comment: Why are you trying to use a static method? Activities only are active when you see them... Your Map variable isn't active  when you go to another activity

Comment: if you really need this, maybe change it to: refresh(Intent intent)?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I think of a solution that solves this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I read the useful comments, I made this `mapReset()` method:

```
public void mapReset() {
    map.clear();
    addAllMarkers();
    //...
}
```

I add this method into the `ChildEventListener` and the map will be reset after I managed the POIs. This solves my problem.

```
poiFirebase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        //...
        mapReset();
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        //...
        mapReset();
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        //...
        mapReset();
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        //...
        mapReset();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
        //...
    }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

A static method is defined *once*, and is not related to a class instance. So you can't modify a class instance with it. What you could do is store your `MapActivity` in a class as a static member, for example:

```
public class World {
    public static MapActivity myMap;
    ...
}
```

Then you can access your map like this:

```
World.myMap.refresh();
```

The difference being that your whole MapActivity is considered a static member, but once you called `World.myMap`, you have a class instance.

Comment: Terrible idea which leads to Activity leak

Comment: @Selvin This is an example as to how you can access staticly an object and use his member functions. Of course this shouldn't be used like that (you will note that this doesn't compile)

Comment: *Of course this shouldn't be used like that* ... then do not post such stuff as many people use SO as references ... Activity should not be putted into static field